# Pass Select Object to function then process with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have several Select Objects on a page that require the same type of processing when an Option is selected. So, I'd like to pass the Select Object(s) to a common function so I only have to write the processing once. I'm doing that, on the onchange() event as follows:

```
<select name="dropDown1" id="dropDown1" onchange="processData(this);">
```

What I'm now wondering, is how can I get the following from the Object passed as a param as such:

```
function processData(obj) {
    // Need to access .index(), .val() and .text() of the obj param
}
```

Here is a complete mock-up:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function processData(obj) {
                // Need to access .index(), .val() and .text() of the obj param
                // Like the following: 
                // var indx = $("select[name='dropDown1'] option:selected").index();
                // ...
            }
        </script>
    </head>   
    <body>
        <div id="container" class="container">
            <select name="dropDown1" id="dropDown1" onchange="processData(this);">
                <option value="1">Red</option>
                <option value="2">Green</option>
                <option value="3">Blue</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: You mean select ***elements*** right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite straightforward:

```
var value = $(obj).val();
// or
var value = obj.value;

var text = $(obj).children('option:selected').text();

var index = $(obj).children('option:selected').index();
// or
var index = obj.selectedIndex;
```

But if you are already using jQuery, then you should also attach the event handler with jQuery.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks! I was trying to replace the name of the Select Object with "obj" in the code, which was why it wasn't working.